# Am I using pcolormesh correctly; why is it not plotting all of my data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following python3.7.6 code gets me close to what I am looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

ex_theta_arr = np.array(range(4,75,1))
ex_times = [0.5, 0.75, 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,30,35]

x_len = len(ex_theta_arr)
y_len = len(ex_times)
ex_data = np.random.random((x_len,y_len))


xx, yy = np.meshgrid(ex_times, ex_theta_arr)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yscale('log')
cs = ax.pcolormesh(yy, xx, ex_data)

ex_x_arr = np.array([ex_theta_arr.min(),ex_theta_arr.max()])

for time in ex_times:
    ax.plot(ex_x_arr, (time, time), 'w-.',linewidth=1)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cs)
```

[image]

However, I expect to see 13 data rows (sections between the white lines) in this plot since 13 is the length of my `times` array. There are only 12, which makes me think one data row is missing... I suspect I am missing something simple, but cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the docs: "the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C, and the quadrilateral is colored due to the value at C[i, j]. If X, Y and C have equal dimensions, a warning will be raised and the last row and column of C will be ignored."

Comment: How would I add 1 to the X and Y dimension in the code example I gave? I tried to add `0` to the beginning of the `times` list, and this worked. But I'm not sure how to add to the X dimension in `ex_theta_arr`.

Comment: With a log scale, you shouldn't add zero. Instead, you could use some small positive value.  If there are 13 white lines, there can only be 12 colored rows. Your `ex_theta_arr` could be `np.arange(4,76))` if you want the first column between 4 and 5 (and the last between 74 and 75). Or `np.arange(3,75))` if you want the first column between 3 and 4 (and the last between 73 and 74). Also note that `ex_data` should be one less in each dimension: `np.random.random((x_len-1,y_len-1))`